# Dialog feed from page, not app

Tags: facebook, dialog

It it possible to link the dialog feed app-link to a page, rather than a app. Or do so the app redirects to the page??

[image]

Thank you in advance... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible for you to change the link/text where it states 'via' as this will always be the application from which the call was made. However you can make use of the `actions` config key.

```
{
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',

    // this is the part you want
    actions: [{
        name: 'My App Page',
        link: 'http://www.apppage.com'
    }]
}
```

Will look like:

[image]

See documentation here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

The link is the `Site URL` specified in the application settings. It have to be a link own by your application, so use a redirect functionality to redirect to the Facebook page with the tab, rather than directly to the solution out of the iframe.